# Why does this string format result in a nil NSDate?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Why does `realDate` end up with a nil value?

```
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let testString = "2015-07-01 05:00:00 +0000"
    let realDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(testString)
```

Comment: pass only the elements you are defining in your date format "2015-07-01

Comment: or define it as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss X"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it does not match the date format. For `realDate` you have it will be next format:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
```

Comment: testString is actually coming from a real date. Is there a way to disregard the time components when doing the format so I have only the date?

Comment: @4thSpace You can do it like this `let testString  = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())` with format: `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"` if I understand what you want to do. This will give the string: `2016-02-26`

Comment: Similar. I'm actually doing dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-07-01") with same format. But it creates the additional time stuff. Is there a way to disregard the time part?

Comment: @4thSpace No, you can just ignore these time values in it future work

Comment: You can't. As you saw above, if you try to remove the time components from the formatter, you get a nil.

Comment: @4thSpace I mean to use the full format, but get only you need from result:)

Comment: "...only you need from result" How?

Comment: @4thSpace You can work with result string to split data you need or you can use `NSCalendar` for example like this: http://bluelemonbits.com/index.php/2015/10/07/get-nsdate-day-month-or-year-in-swift-2-0/

Comment: Ok. I'm splitting the string.  Thanks.